# In git, how can I get a file from the server, after I merged two branches on production, into my local branch?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull

I did a merge of branch A and branch B on the production server(Branch B was merged into branch A). Now there are files that are in branch A that came from branch B as expected. Unfortunately, locally when in Branch A, those files that came from branch B are missing. However, they are in Branch A on the server. How can I pull those files?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion when you do a pull merge the files from the server should come into your local branch.

When this does not happen then try to clone the whole repository again locally from the server.

Comment: I did that and it still is missing the files. I did the below:

git clone /path/to/repo

Comment: I only merged the brancheson the production server. I didn't merge them on my local. I think I have to do that

Comment: With the clone you should get the merged locally, so you should not merge them locally again. When files are missing that means that they were not committed and pushed to the remote.

Comment: What you also can do is that after the clone you add back the files one by one and you commit them again. This would mess your history a bit but you would have at least a working current version. By merging locally, you can do that too and then you compare the merged and cloned from remote with your merged locally.